# Set color CFAttributedStringRef

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this methods for draw a table ant populated . What i want is to change the color for one word from each column , but i dont know how can i do it . Can somebeday help me ,please ? Any help will be appreciate .

in my app the user can select some attributes from segmente control... I want to export what he chosen in a pdf , like a table .So on each line a word will be selected

```
-(void)drawTableDataAt:(CGPoint)origin
         withRowHeight:(int)rowHeight
        andColumnWidth:(int)columnWidth
           andRowCount:(int)numberOfRows
        andColumnCount:(int)numberOfColumns
{
    int padding = 1;

    NSArray* headers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Grand", @"Taile ok", @"Petit", nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Extra", @"Bon", @"Ordi",  nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Gras", @"Etat", @"Maigre", nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cru", @"Propre", @"Sale",  nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo4 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"PLourd", @"PMoyen", @"PLeger", nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo5 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CSup", @"CEgal", @"CInf", nil];


    NSArray* allInfo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:headers, invoiceInfo1, invoiceInfo2, invoiceInfo3, invoiceInfo4, invoiceInfo5,nil];

    for(int i = 0; i < [allInfo count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray* infoToDraw = [allInfo objectAtIndex:i];

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
        {

            int newOriginX = origin.x + (j*columnWidth);
            int newOriginY = origin.y + ((i+1)*rowHeight);

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(newOriginX + padding, newOriginY + padding, columnWidth, rowHeight);


            [self drawText:[infoToDraw objectAtIndex:j] inFrame:frame];
        }

    }

}
```

-(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect
    {

```
    CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)textToDraw;
    // Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter
    CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);


    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

    // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);

    // Get the graphics context.
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
    // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);


    // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
    // the current transform prior to drawing.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw the frame.
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);


    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(stringRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: So one colour per column or?

Comment: one color for one cell from each row. For example i want to make red the next cells: Grand , Bon , Gras,Sale,Pleger and CEgal.

Comment: So basically word will be random and have a set colour? Will this list ever change?

Comment: yes, will be random , and the list with words it 's not changing

Comment: How many colours do you wish to use? Just three?

Comment: Are you using a custom cell with three labels, or just one label?

Comment: two colour....black as diffault and red for the choosen word

Comment: So you want whatever word the user chooses to highlight red? It seems strange that you have gone through this effort to create a table this way. Before I answer, why have you created a table instead of using the default?

Comment: because i didnt found another method to draw a table in a PDF .

Comment: in my app the user can select some attributes from segmente control... I want to export what he chosen in a pdf , like a table .So on each line a word will be selected .

Comment: You really need to have that information in your question that it's related to a PDF and not a view controller. Very confusing. If you are using NSAttributed String then this problem is not to difficult.

Comment: any ideea how to do it ?

Comment: Testing answer now. Will post shortly.

Comment: ok . I'm waiting .  I was try to add :    NSMutableAttributedString *string11 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                           initWithString:textToDraw];
    
    
    
    [string11 addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                     value:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor
                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [string11 length])];
    
but no results

Comment: I have revised the answer, check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question, you mentioned that the words will never change. You could potentially create a whole bunch of if/else statements checking every word selected against every word in an array. I have put this down as a more efficient alternative and it should hopefully work. It may need some tweaking or even a loop to go through your chosen words, but this should hopefully put you in the right direction:

```
//declare your textToDraw as a new NSString
NSString *str = textToDraw;
//Make an Array of the str by adding objects that are separated by whitespace
NSArray *words = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
//create a BOOL to check if your selected word exists in the array
BOOL wordExists = [words containsObject: @"%@", yourSelectedWord];

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = null;

//if the word exists, make it red
if(wordExists){

    NSUInteger indexOfTheString = [words indexOfObject: @"%@", yourSelectedWord];

    CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL,str, NULL);

    [currentText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
         value:[UIColor redColor] 
         range:NSMakeRange(indexOfTheString, yourSelectedWord.length)];

    framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

}
```

This will match your selected word found against the right word in your array and highlight it red.

Comment: and this where should be implemented ? Sorry but it's the first time when i do something like this :(

Comment: in your drawText method. I have not tried this before so it could take some playing around with but in theory it should work. I think you may have done your layout a little more tricky than it could be but I hope this works.

Comment: Sorry just realised. I will have to edit tomorrow as I'm in bed now. It's nearly midnight. I'll update in the morning. If you can't wait, at the top of your drawText method, you can create the right path there.

Comment: place this at the top of your textToDraw method